# Mache dich, mein Herze, rein

Tags: history, imperative, lyrics, metaphor

Ich studiere in dem Chor, in dem ich singe, gerade die [Matthäuspassion](https://konzerthaus.at/konzert/eventid/53118) von J.S.Bach ein. Die Nummer 65 dieses dreieinhalbstündigen Monsterwerks ist eine Arie, die von einem Bass-Solisten gesungen wird. In der ersten Hälfte dieser Arie wird der folgende Satz mehrmals wiederholt:

> **Mache dich, mein Herze, rein**, ich will Jesum selbst begraben.

»*Jesum*« ist vermutlich ein aus dem lateinischen entlehnter Akkusativ von »*Jesus*«, aber darum geht es mir nicht.

Es geht um den fett hervorgehobenen Satz. Den Inhalt verstehe ich, aber die Grammatik widersetzt sich meiner Analyse. Kann jemand diesen Satz für mich analysieren?

Das Musikstück wurde 1727 uraufgeführt. Der Text ist also rund 300 Jahre alt, vermutlich sogar um einiges älter.

---

**Edit (Antwort auf Kommentare):**

Es macht für mich keinen Sinn, mein Herz aufzufordern, sich selbst zu reinigen. Das würde heißen, dass ich ihm einen Befehl bzw. eine Anweisung gebe, und ich mich selbst anschließend auf die faule Haut legen und warten kann, bis das Herz mit der Putzaktion fertig ist. Falls dann das Herz die Reinigung nicht oder nur unvollständig durchführt, ist das nicht meine Schuld, sondern die des Herzens.

Sinnvoller wäre es doch zu sagen, dass ich selbst mein Herz reinigen muss/soll. Denn dabei wäre ich als Akteur direkt in die Reinigung involviert, und ich wäre auch selbst für den Erfolg der Aktion verantwortlich.

Das was mich an der vorgeschlagenen Interpretation des Satzes nach moderner Grammatik verwirrt, ist die sich daraus ergebende Loslösung des Herzens von mir selbst und die daraus notgedrungen resultierende Deutung des Herzens als ein Ding, das von mir Befehle annehmen, und dann, ohne mein weiteres Zutun, auch selbsttätig ausführen kann.

Daher glaube ich nicht, das das so gemeint ist. Ich glaube nicht, dass es ein Imperativ mit direkter Anrede an *mein Herz* ist. Ich glaube, dass der Ich-Erzähler damit ausdrücken will, dass er selbst sein Herz reinigen möchte. Wenn das aber tatsächlich so gemeint ist, dann muss die Satzanalyse, die auf moderner Grammatik basiert, falsch sein. Dem Satz muss also ein heute nicht mehr üblicher grammatischer Bauplan zugrunde liegen. Meine Frage zielt auf diesen Bauplan ab, der vor 300 (oder mehr) Jahren zur Bildung dieses Satzes verwendet wurde.

Comment: Woran hängt es denn? Es ist ein Imperativ mit direkter Anrede an _mein Herz_. – _Jesum_ ist übrigens Akkusativ (Objekt zu _begraben_).

Comment: Hinterfragst du den Sinn hinter einer Aussage, die eine Person in einem Gedicht niedergeschrieben hat? In einer Form der Kunst?

Comment: Es gibt reichlich andere Beispiele bei Bach (und auch davor und danach), in denen das Ich sein Herz wie ein unabhängiges Etwas anredet: _Warum betrübst du dich, mein Herz, bekümmerst dich und trägest Schmerz, nur um das zeitliche Gut?_ (BWV 138) _Merke, mein Herze, beständig nur dies, wenn du alles sonst vergisst, dass dein Heiland lebend ist._ (BWV 145) _Auf, auf, mein Herz, mit Freuden nimm wahr, was heut’ geschieht!_ (BWV 441) _Liebes Herz, bedenke doch deines Jesu große Güte!_ (BWV 482) Selten wird _mein Herz_ auch einmal als eine Art Kosename für Jesus verwendet, das paßt hier aber nicht.

Comment: Siehe auch: Geh' aus, mein Herz, und suche Freud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Mein Herz" muss hier im biblischen Sinne verstanden werden, da es sich um ein auf der Bibel aufbauendes Werk handelt, von dem wir hier sprechen.

Die Satzanalyse, Imperativ mit direkter Anrede, ist richtig. Wichtig ist das Weltbild, welches uns zeigt, wer hier direkt angesprochen wird.

Offensichtlich ist nicht der Muskel gemeint, der Blut durch unseren Körper pumpt. Auch heute noch verstehen wir das Herz ja als Sitz unserer Emotionen, weil sich die Emotionen oft auf das Herz auswirken.

Zur Frage: im Hebräischen und Altgriechischen steht das mit Herz übersetzte Wort jeweils für unser Innerstes, unser wahres Ich, unsere Seele, unser Leben.

Das biblische Menschenbild unterscheidet auch nicht griechisch scharf zwischen den einzelnen Teilen des Menschen, Körper, Seele, Geist.

Der Satz im biblischen Sinne bedeutet nicht mehr als eine Aufforderung an mich selbst als ganzen Menschen, mein Denken, Fühlen, Wollen, mich zu reinigen, d.h. Frieden zu schliessen mit Gott und Vergebung zu suchen.

Wenn ich mein Herz auffordere, etwas zu tun, ist es das genaue Gegenteil davon, einem Teil von mir zu befehlen und mich danach zurückzulehnen.

Unser vom griechisch-lateinischen Weltbild des Divide et impera, Teile und herrsche, beherrschtes Weltbild und Menschenverständnis wurde hauptsächlich durch die aufkommende Wissenschaft in der Aufklärung wieder zum dominanten Weltbild. In religiösen Fragen zur Zeit des Entstehung dieses Werkes herrschte aber ein holistischeres Menschenbild vor.

Biblische Vorbilder sind Verse wie:

Aber sei nur stille zu Gott, meine Seele; denn er ist meine Hoffnung. Ps 62:5

Was betrübst du dich, meine Seele, und bist so unruhig in mir? Harre auf Gott! Ps 43:5

Und besonders deutlich in:

Lobe den HERRN, meine Seele, und was in mir ist, seinen heiligen Namen! Ps 103:2

Answer (score 13):

Die Kommentare sagen es schon: Es ist eine direkte Anrede an "mein Herz", das rein werden soll, um Jesus ganz aufnehmen zu können.

Comment: Nein, das glaube ich nicht. Näheres habe der Frage hinzugefügt.

Comment: Doch, das ist schon richtig so. Er spricht sein Herz an und fordert es auf, sich frei/rein zu machen. Wir wollen mal bedenken, wann Bach so gelebt hat und wie damals gesprochen wurde und auch die Tatsache, dass wir von einem lyrischen Text und nicht von einer biologischen Abhandlung sprechen. Ähnlich übrigens in *Geh aus / mein hertz / und suche freud / In dieser lieben sommerzeit* von Paul Gerhardt.

Answer (score 12):

Das ist in der Poesie ein klassisches Muster auch außerhalb des biblischen Kontexts; ich hoffe ein anderer Antworter hat den Fachbegriff dafür parat, einen fiktiven Stellvertreter zu benennen und den dann zu adressieren, anstatt über sich selbst zu sprechen. Dass sich der Sprecher hier selbst (demütig?) aus der erzählerischen Linie nimmt, mag ein beabsichtiger Nebeneffekt sein.

Beispiele:

> 1825, Ernst Schulze:  Liedtext: O Herz, sei endlich stille! / Was schlägst du so unruhvoll? /  Es ist ja des Himmels Wille, /  Daß ich sie lassen soll. (Vertont von Franz Schubert, D 860)

oder:

> Trink, o Auge, was die Wimper hält, / von dem goldnen Überfluß der Welt. (Gottfried Keller)

Comment: Abspaltung, Verleugnung, Projektion, Personifikation?

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist meine - rein subjektive - einen obigen Kommentar ergänzende Deutung des Liedtextes:

„Mein Herz“ ist ein mystisches Wahrnehmungsorgan; es ist auch der Sitz von Emotionen, emotionaler Motivation, Liebe und Trauer, ist berührbar, kann erfüllt oder leer sein. Die mystische Wahrnehmungsfunktion ist eine empfangende. Sie kann das Göttliche nur empfangen, wenn es leer von der Welt ist, von jeglichem Wollen, vermeintlichem Haben oder Wissen des Weltlichen oder des vermeintlich gewussten Spirituellen. Die Wahrheit wird nicht von uns selbst gemacht, sie ist kein Menschenwerk. Sie kann allerdings empfangen werden. („Empfangen“ finde ich noch passender, als die Bezeichnung „aufnehmen“ meines Vorredners.) Wie mache ich nun mein Herz, empfangsbereit? Indem ich es „rein“ mache, d. h. leer und unschuldig. Es ähnelt der hinduistischen und buddhistischen Leere, als Erkenntnisort und als Wahrheit selbst. Nach christlicher Beschreibung kann die unerlöste Seele, symbolisiert durch Maria, mit ihrem „reinen Herz“, d. h. im Zustand und am inneren Ort der Unschuld und der Reinheit, das Heilige in sich empfangen. So inkarniert das Heilige / Gott, wird empfangen und geboren im Menschen. Der so empfangen und in uns geboren wird, ist Jesus, geboren als Mensch und eins mit Gott. Geschieht dies in uns, verschwindet der außerhalb von uns gedachte Jesus, wird „begraben“ von mir und hat „in mir seine süße Ruhe“. Was ich dafür tun kann, ist, dass mein Herz sich rein macht - die Empfängnis ist ein Geschenk, eine Gnade, die dann kommen und wahr—genommen werden kann.
Uwe

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Die Reihenfolge der Posts ist nicht von Dauer, daher bitte "Antwort des Vorredners" direkt verlinken. Falls möglich, dann bitte noch Quellen angeben/verlinken, die die Argumente so darlegen. Z.B. die mystische Funktion etc.. Allgemein ist - soweit möglich - die objektive Deutung von Dingen gesucht.

Answer (score 0):

Pars pro toto. Das Herz steht für die vollständige Person. "Mein Herz" ist auch als Kosename für einen geliebten Menschen üblich. [Zitat](https://www.orbis-uebersetzungen.de/liebe-kennt-keine-grenzen-kosenamen-im-internationalen-vergleich/):

> Lernen kann der Deutsche dagegen besonders von den Arabern. „Meine Seele“, „mein Augenlicht“ oder „mein Leben“ dürften in dieser Hinsicht eindeutig mehr Aussicht auf Erfolg besitzen. Die Spanier kommen dem schon ziemlich nahe; „mein Herz“ (auch in Frankreich durchaus beliebt), oder „Himmel auf Erden“ vermitteln auf geradezu poetische Art und Weise ein hohes Maß an Zuneigung.